# Does DELETE complete after stopping the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I execute a statement like this:

```
DELETE FROM Person WHERE PersonNo in (
select PersonNo from Person
left join SportsPerson on Person.PersonNo=SportsPerson.PersonNo
)
```

This will delete all persons not linked to a sport.  Say it took two hours to run (because the database is not indexed) and I decided to stop the process in SQL Studio Manager (perhaps because of locks on the table causing access issues with the application), then does the process complete? I ran a test and it appears that is does.

I know I should wrap the statement in a transaction.   I am just curious about this.

Comment: seems your query will delete all rows except where personno is null. Are you missing a WHERE SportsPerson.PersonNo is null ?

Answer (score 1):

It will stop the query and releases lock unless you used hold lock

and you can ROLLBACK if you want or can COMMIT it..

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the default is rollback if you do not do either?+1.